# Decoding a X509 Certificate in Human readable format - Golang

Tags: go, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

I have the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/dsa"
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // Verifying with a custom list of root certificates.

    const rootPEM = `
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

    const certPEM = `
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

    // First, create the set of root certificates. For this example we only
    // have one. It's also possible to omit this in order to use the
    // default root set of the current operating system.
    roots := x509.NewCertPool()
    ok := roots.AppendCertsFromPEM([]byte(rootPEM))
    if !ok {
        panic("failed to parse root certificate")
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(certPEM))
    if block == nil {
        panic("failed to parse certificate PEM")
    }
    cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to parse certificate: " + err.Error())
    }

    // I want to print cert.Raw in human readable format
    fmt.Println(string(cert.Raw))
}
```

However, I keep getting something like:

```
0I10??}E*?H??0
   0    UUS10U

140529000000Z0i1oogle Internet Authority G20
                0   UUS10U

California10U
Mountain View10U


Google Inc10U
             mail.google.com0Y0*?H?*?H?=B}?n??>??)???kG? ???DrK????
7վ??h?y
       ??9  ??I??oz\?B?4u?????O0?K0U%+0U0?mail.google.com0
                                                              U?0+\0Z0+0?http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt0+0?http://clients1.google.com/ocsp0U??m?`.M??-~T`??*?0
                U?00U#0?J??h?v????b?Z?/0U 00

??X?pjL?Q7??s??v??!6??,</i.google.com/GIAG2.crl0
ͦ``?jT+?I7?V??&2??*?(D?"im?A*?;?N???^??o???<?ˆ???X0M?uv?F?k?X?N??V???w0?f绶#b?2
?????C8?P)m?????O??RK?Ӷ~??#??#?Ϡ??m<3[?u!?b#?]?1?d
                                                   ?
```

How can I get the human readable format for the certificate?

Comment: What do you mean by "human readable"? Do you want to re-encode it in PEM format?

Comment: @JimB do you see how the output from the ``fmt.Println(string(cert.Raw))`` looks like? I want to have a human-readable format ... instead of ``"im?A*?;?N???^??o???<?ˆ???X0M?uv?F?k?X?N??V???w0?f绶#b?2
?????C8?P)m?????O??RK?Ӷ~??#??#?Ϡ??m<3[?u!?b#?]?1?d"``

Comment: But you're printing the "Raw" field, which is the original ASN.1 DER bytes. You already parsed the ASN.1 into the `Certificate`, which contains many human readable fields.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `String() string` member function in `x509.Certificate` so you will need to write one yourself.

e.g.

```
fmt.Println(cert.Subject)
fmt.Println(cert.Issuer)
fmt.Println(decodeAlgorithm(cert.PublicKeyAlgorithm))


func decodeAlgorithm(code x509.PublicKeyAlgorithm) string {
    var s string
    switch code {
    case x509.RSA:
            s = "RSA"
    case x509.DSA:
            s = "DSA"
    case x509.ECDSA:
            s = "ECDSA"
    default:
            s = "oops"
    }
    return s
}
```

When I ran this on *.google.com PEM, I get

```
{[US] [Google Inc] [] [] [] [] []  Google Internet Authority G2 [{2.5.4.6 US} {2.5.4.10 Google Inc} {2.5.4.3 Google Internet Authority G2}] []}
{[US] [GeoTrust Inc.] [] [] [] [] []  GeoTrust Global CA [{2.5.4.6 US} {2.5.4.10 GeoTrust Inc.} {2.5.4.3 GeoTrust Global CA}] []}
RSA
```